# NextJs: Issue with first initial render after build

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13

**Server-Side:** 
[I am extracting host from the context.ctx.req.headers and sending it down as a part pageProps using getInitialProps in _app.tsx.](https://github.com/Shreyaschorge/web-app-clone/blob/aff247d119974cf9720719c44d328e98e4abdb39/pages/_app.tsx#L354)

**Client-Side:** 
[I am getting the host from the pageProps and logging it to the console.](https://github.com/Shreyaschorge/web-app-clone/blob/aff247d119974cf9720719c44d328e98e4abdb39/pages/_app.tsx#L142)

**Issue**
When I deploy the application on vercel, for the first initial render after build, the logs don't run because `pageProps.host=undefined` after refreshing though it works even for subsequent initial renders.